# How can I restrict login to Azure LINUX VM using AAD integration

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines

I have an Azure Linux Virtual Machine with "Login with Azure AD" option enabled.

But I am still able to log into with admin account using password.

Or I can just create another user by using Reset Password option under Help section in VM.

And this new user is also able to log into the VM.

How can I restrict so that only login via AAD is permitted and all the other options are blocked.

---

I tried changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config to values:

PasswordAuthentication no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

UsePAM no

And also /etc/security/access.conf

.# User "root" should be denied to get access from all other sources.

-:root:ALL

.# All other users should be denied to get access from all sources.

-:ALL:ALL

Comment: The AADLoginForLinux is being deprecated on 2021-08-15. Please use the new extension, SSH based, AADSSHLoginForLinux. Which extension do you use?

Comment: Right now I am using AADSSHLoginForLinux